# Is this method overloading?

Tags: java, overloading

I have created two methods in java;

```
public int sum(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

public double sum(int a, double b){
    return a+b;
}
```

and from main(), i call ;

```
System.out.println(sum(1,2));
System.out.println(sum(1,2.5));
```

and works fine and the output is correct;

3
3.5

So, should we call this overloading or a different method ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is method overloading

Comment: Have you tried to read something about ["method overloading"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)? If yes, what is/was unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is overloading.

There are two ways in java to overload a method:

1. By changing number of arguments
2. By changing the data type

However method overloading is not possible by changing only the return type of the method.

Comment: There is one way: by changing the parameter list. What exactly you've changed (number of arguments or their types) doesn't matter.

Comment: just had confusion about the return type, which now cleared, i.e. function can be overloaded even if they have diff return types

Answer (score 0):

It is both.

`sum(int, double)` and `sum(int, int)` are different methods, even though they have the same name.

*Method overloading* is *the ability to create different methods with the same name and different parameters*. Here, you are creating different methods with the same name and different parameters, so you are using method overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods have same name,same return type and different arguments then simply they are overloaded methods

```
void run(int a)
void run(int a, double b)
```